# How to see source code of a demonstration in notebook

Tags: notebooks

I downloaded this  [demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RungesPhenomenon/)

The source code can be previewed [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/sourcecode.html?demoname=RungesPhenomenon&demodisplayname=Runge%27s%20Phenomenon)
However, when I download the NB file, I cannot get access to this said code. All I can see is the output.

I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: Double-click the brackets on the right side of the notebook to expand the hidden contents.

Comment: @phosgene it works, thank you very much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Double-click on the cell bracket to expand it.  The arrow on the bracket indicates that it is closed and can be expanded downwards.

[image]